# How to get all columns of a class in Parse PHP?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using this code:

```
$schema = new ParseSchema();
$schema->className("Brand");
$class = $schema->get();
print_r($class);die();
```

But I'm not getting a response actually I'm getting a 500 error!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The server error logs should contain a detailed error message

Comment: Is there a way to see logs on Parse.com? thanks

Comment: I don't know parse.com so I can't say, but I'm sure there is. I'd start by checking their support resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more into this it turned out that the right code for this issue is:

```
$schema = new ParseSchema("Brand");
$class = $schema->get();
print_r($class);die();
```

className is private it can't be accessed, so we need the set the className when starting new object on the constructor level.